# Is there a way to join/merge records real time in Kafka Streams?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have various data sources, which are pushing updates on the same records to our exposed API. When we receive an update from any source,

We push that record to TopicA,

```
Source1 -> {Update, "Time{14/06/2019 1:27:56}"} 
Source2 -> {Update,"Time{14/06/2019 1:27:58}" }
```

in this case

We might receive an update from Source1 first due to network latency from Source. However, we want to solve this using join/merge Kafka Stream KTable. Does this scenario Solvable using KTable, KStream?

Comment: Your use case description is rather high level, but I sound like a good use-case for Kafka Streams.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask